# Transform SPOT5 images to natural color images

Tags: algorithm, remote-sensing

We're currently using PixelSense to convert raw SPOT5 images to natural color ones for display and printing. Do you know a good algorithm to perform the same task as we want to ingest raw images in an image server and provide an image service with on the fly natural color conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is to perform these steps:

- generate a synthetic blue channel
- balance the colors by outlier removal through analysing the channel historgrams. For a GPL'ed approach, see [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass/branches/releasebranch_6_4/scripts/i.landsat.rgb/i.landsat.rgb)
- then create the RGB composite

Concerning the generating of a synthetic blue channel:

Since I don't have SPOT5 data here, I cannot make a test. But I found this formula ([Knudsen](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass/branches/releasebranch_6_4/scripts/i.landsat.rgb/i.landsat.rgb)):

```
Blue_synth = 0.70 × Green + 0.24 × Red - 0.14 × NIR
```

Comment: The first step is where the magic lies, I guess. Care to elaborate please ?

Comment: I have edited my previous answer, see above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ESRI software; check out this thread: http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=982&t=271727&mc=10#msgid841178