# True color combination using Resourcesat-1?

Tags: raster, remote-sensing, multi-band

I am working with an image from India. According to the metadata, I am working with an image acquired by the ***AWiFS*** sensor from ***Resourcesat-1***:

```
<Name_of_the_Satellite>Resourcesat-1</Name_of_the_Satellite>
<Sensor>AWiFS</Sensor>
```

Which according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resourcesat-1) uses the following bands:

[image]

Each band was delivered in a separate image, so I have stacked them.

Now, my question is how to get a ***true color*** combination using those bands.

I remember that the following wavelengths correspond (more or less) to the following colors in the electromagnetic spectrum:

0.4-0.5 µm: B
0.5-0.6 µm: G
0.6-0.7 µm: R

Looking at the chart above, I realize that **Blue** is missing. So, is it even possible to get a true color image from these bands? If not, *what would be the closest I can get*?

My remote sensing skills are a little rusty as I am not working with imagery too much. I hope my question is clear. I am using QGIS 2.6.0 (what I used to stack the images), in case that makes any difference, but I am open to other options as well.

Comment: You could try to fake a blue band, have a Google for "Spot 5 natural colour algorithm,  eg http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/3916 Another option is to download a Landsat scene of the area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't.

The [documentation](http://www.dsc.nrsc.gov.in/DSC/ForestFire/index.jsp?Aa=IRS_P6.jsp) says:

> The Advanced Wide Field Sensor (AWiFS), on-board IRS-P6 operates in
>   four spectral bands in green (0.52-0.59µm), red (0.62-0.68µm), near
>   infrared (0.77-0.86µm) and short wave infrared (1.55-1.70µm)

Since the data does not have the regular 3 bands, you cannot get a True color composite of the data

Comment: That is what I expected, glad you could confirm it. Do you have any suggestion how I could at least get close to it?

Comment: Since the Blue Band is missing, you can't get anything close to a true color composite. The only thing you could get is a standard FCC

Comment: That clarifies everything, so I will mark the answer as accepted!

PS: since you are from India, can you suggest a good source for TCC imagery?

Comment: I've used Landsat 8 in 4,3,2 combination as suggested here: http://landsat.usgs.gov/L8_band_combos.php